# String include string ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a string like this

```
string = 'Company Bla potato text 123 random foo bar'
```

How can I detect including string in string?

```
string.include?('potato') => true
string.include?('Company Bla') => true
```

this work fine
but how I can detect these cases:

```
string.include?('Potato') => false
string.include?('Company BLA') => false
string.include?('RANDOM') => false
```

they return false but I need true.

Answer (score 6):

One simple way is to make both downcase or uppercase

```
s = 'Potato'
string.downcase.include?(s.downcase)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
s = "Company BLA"
p string.match?(/#{s}/i)
```

The trailing `i` tells the regex to ignore case.

Comment: `string.match?(/#{Regexp.escape s}/i)`. Yours would fail if there is a slash or something in a matcher.